# Why don't we have 'inverted' atoms with electrons in the nucleus and protons orbiting around?

Tags: reference-frames, electrons, atomic-physics, inertial-frames, protons

I just wanted to ask: What if the structure of an atom was inverted at the level of the charges? I mean that instead of the protons being in the nucleus it is an the electrons that constitute the nucleus and the protons orbit around.

Here is what I mean by that:
[image: The image representation]

Here is the question, if this is not possible then why is it so?

Comment: Protons and electrons are **not** opposites, they may have opposite charge but their masses differ by a lot.

Comment: So that would completely be dependent on the masses rather than their charges? Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: This is analogous to asking whether you could have the Earth almost stationary at the center of the Solar System and the much more massive Sun orbiting around it.

Comment: Although charge also does matter because we have proof that C-symmetry does not always hold.

Comment: In order to do that you should be able to build nuclei with electrons and perhaps neutrons. Since protons and neutrons are made of quarks the strong force is able to overcome the electronic repulsion and produce a bound state. The same doesn't work with electrons because there is no strong interaction between them.

Comment: BTW why closing? This is a perfectly valid question, perhaps simply changing the what-if style to: why can't we have inverted atoms?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to reverse the structure of the atom. Electrons have a very low mass and (relatively) protons are quite massive. Because of the uncertainty relationship between position and momentum the more tightly confined a particle is the more certain its position and the more uncertain its momentum.

As the uncertainty in momentum increases so does the expected energy, and so this effect defines the ground state such that a less massive particle is less tightly confined than a more massive particle when each is in their respective ground state in the same potential. Thus, strictly from the rules of QM, the less massive particle will always have the larger orbital in the ground state.